# Rails Paperclip: missing required :bucket option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I've got Heroku working fine with paperclip, but I'm getting this error when I move the app over to a linux box, the logs show that imagemagick processing finishes and then it fails on upload:

`ArgumentError (missing required :bucket option):`

My application.yml includes:

```
S3_BUCKET_NAME: "bucket"
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: "key"
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: "secret"
```

I've doubled-checked that all of that info is correct. `production.rb` includes:

```
  config.paperclip_defaults = {
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => {
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
    }
```

I've reset the server and redeployed to reload the initializers. Is there a way to see ENV variables in rails c on a linux box to see if they're set correctly? I know on heroku you can just do `heroku config`. I suspect this may be due to my lack of understanding of rails ENV vars

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18794779/rails-paperclip-s3-argumenterror-missing-required-bucket-option

Answer (score 0):

I was missing `gem 'figaro'` in my production env, so none of the ENV variables were being set.